# How can I make a polygon from intersecting lines of different layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping, polygonize, map-drawing, geology

I am constructing a geological map which involves constructing boundaries to areas which vary in style across their length depending on how well defined they. To do this I have created two distinct layers called "certain" and "inferred", one solid the other dashed. I wish to automatically create a polygon fill surrounded by the boundaries, but when I use the lines -> polygon tool, I am only given the option to select one layer at a time.

Can I join the two layers together into one but retaining the changing style?

Alternatively, can I possibly change the style of the line within one layer, or can each layer only have one style?

Comment: Each layer can only have **one** style -> each style can have **multiple** symbol items. Therefore, you can have one solid line **and** one dashed line in a single layer. Just change the _Single Symbol_ setting to another such as _Categorized_ or _Rule-based_ etc and in the symbol options (double-click on a symbol), add a new symbol item (green plus sign) and play around with the settings.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph this is great for what I wanted with the lines. Unfortunately however the default 'lines -> polygon'  algorithm cannot cope with the fact that the enclosed area is made up of seperate features, despite their intersection. From my searching it looks like the 'Polygonize' plugin would be helpful here, but I cannot find it on the plugins list, do you know how to get hold of it?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked out how to do this!

Using the *Categorized* line styles I generated multiple different styles for bits of the line. I then constructed joined up lines (using snapping tool to make sure they overlapped) which created closed shapes. I then ran the polygonize tool like so:

"Processing -> Commander" and then typing 'Polygonize' and following the instructions.